# How to adapt bootstrap modal width to contained image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal to create a thumbnail gallery that displays an attemp of full-size images when its thumbnail is clicked.

I managed to make everything work fine and changed the css a bit but I don't find the way to change the modal div width to be adapted to the image within in. Basically I want to do this so the image is displayed full-sized.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="galeria" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should I do to achieve my goal? I am using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Add some more information here. What version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: Did you eventually find the answer?

Comment: this was over a year ago so I don't even remember the context of asking this. But I think I ended up using a plugin, maybe the one proposed by kamuken, yeah that one seems familiar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try boostrap image gallery modul

```
http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/
```

you can make responsive moduls with this